# galaxy grand duos gt-i9082l don't start

Tags: unbricking, restore

Well, I have a Galaxy Grand Duos GT-I9082L brasilian version and i try restore my phone with kies, but i still get this error
[image]

I try restore with odin, but result are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have to do a hard reset and flash it with a new or Custom ROM and optionally with Gapps. If you have a backup of your stock ROM, then try flashing it. Follow the steps from [Xda deveopers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/). Be sure to search by your phone model and variant.

Comment: my solution was hard reset w/ ADB, thaks!